# BIRT: change font chart axis

Tags: charts, birt

i have a big report with all the text of grid, table, html element with fontFamily='Arial'. When i create a chart the list of font family is this: ['Cursive', 'Fantasy', 'Monospace', 'San-Serif','Serif'].

There is a way to change the font of chart to 'Arial' and not to one of these?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse designer, select the "outline view" of your report and right click "Styles" section:

*-> New Style -> Predefined Style -> Select Report Element -> Chart*

Click "Font", select Arial in the drop-down list and OK.

Now all charts of this report will use by default Arial, unless you override it specifically in "Format chart" editor sections.

Comment: Sorry Dominique, 
your solution is good, in my case remain the problem because the machine when i have the server doesn't have the 'Arial' font configured.